# How to center flip book before and after flip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to autocenter this flip book on the page so it stays centred when flipped or not. Ive used the flip.js documentation of `autoCenter`, as well as `$("#flipbook").turn("center");` but nothing works. Does anyone know if this can be done? A working example is in the fiddle below:-

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/GGea5/1/

```
      <div class="t">
          <div class="tc rel">
              <div class="book" id="book">
                  <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/02.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/03.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/05.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/06.jpg" alt="" /></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>




                            /*
             * Turn.js responsive book
             */

            /*globals window, document, $*/

            (function () {
                'use strict';

                var module = {
                    ratio: 1.38,
                    init: function (id) {
                        var me = this;

                        // if older browser then don't run javascript
                        if (document.addEventListener) {
                            this.el = document.getElementById(id);
                            this.resize();
                            this.plugins();

                            // on window resize, update the plugin size
                            window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
                                var size = me.resize();
                                $(me.el).turn('size', size.width, size.height);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    resize: function () {
                        // reset the width and height to the css defaults
                        this.el.style.width = '';
                        this.el.style.height = '';

                        var width = this.el.clientWidth,
                            height = Math.round(width / this.ratio),
                            padded = Math.round(document.body.clientHeight * 0.9);

                        // if the height is too big for the window, constrain it
                        if (height > padded) {
                            height = padded;
                            width = Math.round(height * this.ratio);
                        }

                        // set the width and height matching the aspect ratio
                        this.el.style.width = width + 'px';
                        this.el.style.height = height + 'px';

                        return {
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        };
                    },
                    plugins: function () {
                        // run the plugin
                        $(this.el).turn({
                            gradients: true,
                            acceleration: true
                        });
                        // hide the body overflow
                        document.body.className = 'hide-overflow';
                    }
                };

                module.init('book');
            }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I missed putting this autocenter at the bottom of the code:-

```
            plugins: function () {
                // run the plugin
                $(this.el).turn({
                    gradients: true,
                    acceleration: true,
                    autoCenter: true
                });
                // hide the body overflow
                document.body.className = 'hide-overflow';
            }
```